# Android Immersive Mode Transitions

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, android-transitions

I have an android app which uses immersive mode for all activities - so its a full fullscreen app.

I have a BaseActivity class from which all other activities extend. In this activity I call the following to enable fullscreen/immersive

HelmiBlankActivity:

```
private boolean apiLowerImmersive = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        apiLowerImmersive = true;
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

  if(hasFocus && !apiLowerImmersive ) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```

In activities it works great, the problem is: When opening a new activity (per intent) the actionbar/titlebar are displayed for a short time and then hidden again - which seems kind of laggy/buggy.

The Application also has a theme: 
styles.xml:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I have tried applying the android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar as well - no success during transitions. 
I could not find anything on stackoverflow (which btw is a great community and has helped me with many problems) or anywhere else on the internet and would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put this snippet into onCreate() method your activities will open with the bars already hidden.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

You can also add conditions for older SDKs. The only problem I've got with this setup is the fact that once i swipe down to show bars, they won't hide again...

Comment: Thanks - that did it! About the problem with the bars not going away: thats only happening on a few devices - cant find any clues what the reasons for that are

Comment: In order to hide the bars again automatically, you should use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY instead of SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.